# Import Japanese text data in database

Tags: database, import

I imported japanese text data in my database. The text data changed.

From this text data **"振り仮名"** after importing the data becomes **"????"**

I'm using sqlite manager to import my data.sql file.

Inside data.sql is something like:

INSERT INTO tablename
VALUES(1, "振り仮名", "振り仮名", "振り仮名")

Thanks for the help.

Comment: which database?, what structure? how did you import? It's almost certainly an encoding issue, but it will help if you define your environment

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check if your table correctly set encoding to UTF8?

If not you can change it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE db_modeling_tools
    CHARACTER SET utf8,
    COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Secondly, if the first one is correctly set, try to do this before SELECT command:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SELECT name FROM db_modeling_tools WHERE is_online = true ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT 1;
```

You may see it works correctly.

Hope it helps :)